# why does Django Slice works on one page and not the other

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

This allows me to slice

**#models.py**

```
Class Home(models.Model):
    house_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=True)
    rooms = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=True)



def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = slugify(self.house_name)
    super(Home, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**#views.py**

```
def homes(request):
home_model = Home.objects.filter(admin_approval=True)
return render(request, 'home/home.html', {'home_model': home_model})
```

**#home.html**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row row-cols-lg-4 row-cols-md-3 text-center text-light">
{% for home in home_model|slice:":10" %}

    <div class="row-inside-content"> 
        <a href="{% url 'home_detail' home.slug %}"><img src="#"></a>
        <p><a href="#">{{ home.home_name|title }}</a></p>
    </div>
```

{% endfor %}

```
  </div>
```

Meanwhile if I was to use the same views, and same model and also try to render homes in another page like home/house.html, nothing gets render. I'm utterly confused as to why this is happening.

Comment: You'll need to provide the full code listing for the part that's not working if you want feedback, very difficult to just guess what the problem might be ;)

Comment: I just simply copied and pasted what was on my html file to another file and nothing was render. What I’m trying to achieve is something like a list of the first registered homes in my model. I have a home/home.html page where I render every home, but I would also like to display only a limited number of homes on another page (home/houses.html).